# Android set different theme for two Fragment like Play Store

Tags: android, android-viewpager, themes

how can I replicate the effect of swap theme change as seen from the example?

At the moment with setTheme() does not seem to work dynamically.

[Play Store Effect](https://giphy.com/gifs/play-store-3ohhwuylwIjVDOJh0A)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no dynamic themes getting applied there. Each fragment inside viewpager has their elements themed before depending on their topic. If you want to know how the Toolbar animation is done I can suggest an approach which will give you the same result.

Play store layout

```
<Toolbar>
    <FrameLayout>
        <RelativeLayout id="toolbarContainer">
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout id="revealContainer">
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TabLayout></TabLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</Toolbar>
<StoreView></StoreView><!-- This is where you see viewpager fragments -->
```

The process will be:

- You start [Circular Reveal Animation](https://medium.com/@daniele.orlando/beautiful-circular-reveal-animation-on-android-1b5aaca2dd1f) on ***revealContainer*** inside onPageSelected of your OnPageChangeListener.
- On animation end you set the background of the of ***toolbarContainer***.
- Hide the ***revealContainer***

The code would look something like this

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
// new position of page
showRevealEffectForPage(position);
}
});

private void showRevealEffectForPage(int page) {
int color;
switch(page) {
case 0:
color = Color.parseColor("#fff"); //white
break;
default:
color = Color.parseColor("#000"); //black
break;
}

//set color before animation starts
revealContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

int x = revealContainer.getRight();
int y = revealContainer.getBottom();

int startRadius = 0;
int endRadius = (int) Math.hypot(toolbarContainer.getWidth(), toolbarContainer.getHeight());

Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(revealContainer, x, y, startRadius, endRadius);

layoutButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// you can set animation listener here to check for when the animation ends by

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
//set the color of toolbarContainer
toolbarContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
revealContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});

anim.start();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it's simply theming the elements. If it were just that, the primary color wouldn't change, but when you open the Recents screen the Playstore's title bar color is the same color as the tab you are, this can only mean that the primary color is really changing. I don't know how it's done, but I'm searching for an answer too

Comment: @LuccasClezar I assume setTheme(R.style.YourTheme); _[inside which colorPrimary is different]_ is called. This is probably set after tab is changed.

Comment: @codekidX yeah, I know about `setTheme` but I read that it can only be called before setting the layout... I didn't try to use it yet though, so I don't know if it's true